# Installing a small footprint windows server 2008 on Azure

Tags: azure, licensing, windows-server-2008

I want to install a w2k8 on windows azure **on a disk of 25Gb**.
If I choose an image from the VMs galery, it installs on a disk of 127Gb (five times my need).

So I guess I must install localy, run sysprep and upload it to azure (I have detalis of how to do this from my googles).  But **I do not own w2k8**. My questions are:

Can I use a 180 days traial of w2k8 to make my setup on a 25Gb VHD?
Will it work after the 180 days period?  //becouse it is on Azure???
Is this process "licence-compliant"?
Is there other way to obtanin the same I want?

(edit) I am offering a bounty becouse I am having partial anwsers to my four questions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maarten Balliauw wrote a nice blog post on how to resize a VHD on Windows Azure.  It was focused on extending a virtual disk, not on shrinking one, but it might also works (I only tested the extend, not the shrink).
This way of work would at least save you hours of upload and sysprepping, so I would say it's worth a try by creating a new virtual machine from the gallery, shut down the machine, delete it and the disk (not the VHD) and then apply the resize.

The blog post is here: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2013/01/07/Tales-from-the-trenches-resizing-a-Windows-Azure-virtual-disk-the-smooth-way.aspx

Hope it works

Comment: +1 good article. but i got serious doubt about shrink with this method

Comment: It should be quick enough to test. If it works, then I think this is the best option. Alternatively, if you really doubt the ability to this in Azure, you could always just download it and do it locally and then re-upload it overnight.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want a smaller disk?  You only pay for the amount of storage you are actually using, so for the 127 GB image galleries you are only paying storage costs for the amount of data you have written to the disk.

Comment: I do not understud that from my readings (perhaps I am wrong).  I understand that "the amount of storage that you are using" is the amount of storage that you have seted up

Comment: See the "Storage Capacity" section under Billing at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/28/data-series-exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx.